# invalid operation: type interface {} does not support indexing

Tags: json, dictionary, go, unmarshalling, type-assertion

I'm new to the golang and I have problem while reading the nested JSON response.

```
var d interface{}
json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&d)
test :=d["data"].(map[string]interface{})["type"]
```

`response.Body` looks like this

```
{
    "links": {
      "self": "/domains/test.one"
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "domains",
        "id": "test.one",
        "attributes": {
            "product": " Website",
            "package": "Professional",
            "created_at": "2016-08-19T11:37:01Z"
        }
    }
}
```

The Error I'm getting is this:

```
invalid operation: d["data"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

Comment: This is a pretty good resource https://gobyexample.com/json

Comment: @jeff i'm using interface assuming that i don't know the structure of response.

Comment: @Jeff   it works but assuming if i have to parse nested element  this solution will be  complex.
 do you have any alternate solution ?

Answer (score 19):

`d` is of type `interface{}`, so you cannot index it like `d["data"]`, you need another type assertion:

```
test := d.(map[string]interface{})["data"].(map[string]interface{})["type"]
fmt.Println(test)
```

Then it will work. Output will be `"domains"`. See a working example on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HZDAaxV5QW).

Also note that if you declare `d` to be of type `map[string]interface{}`, you can spare the first type assertion:

```
var d map[string]interface{}
if err := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&d); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
test := d["data"].(map[string]interface{})["type"]
fmt.Println(test)
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6X6nFCw1-e).

If you need to do these and similar operations many times, you may find my [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://github.com/icza/dyno) library useful (whose primary goal is to aid working with dynamic objects).

Comment: Tip for newbies like me: To understand why this code works, one should understand how `Decode` works, which is related to `unmarshal`. The `json.Unmarshal` doc explains how it stores data.

Comment: > if you declare d to be of type map[string]interface{}, you can spare the first type assertion

--> you MUST spare the first type assertion

Answer (score 0):

You need some tricks to handle your situation.
Like using reflect and you may ref Marshall&&UnMarshall code about bson.M in [golang mongo driver mgo](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2-unstable/bson/bson.go)

code sample using reflect decode nested as following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    keys := []string{"hello", "world", "dude", "kind", "cool"}
    a := make(map[string]interface{})
    a[keys[4]] = "perfect"
    b := make(map[string]interface{})
    b[keys[3]] = a
    c := make(map[string]interface{})
    c[keys[2]] = b
    d := make(map[string]interface{})
    d[keys[1]] = c
    e := make(map[string]interface{})
    e[keys[0]] = d
    fmt.Println(e)

    if buf, err := json.Marshal(e); nil == err {
        dd := make(map[string]interface{})
        err = json.Unmarshal(buf, &dd)
        if nil != err {
            fmt.Println("failed", err)
        }

        for k, v := range dd {
            travel(dd, k, v)
        }
        fmt.Println(dd)

    } else {
        fmt.Println("failed marshal")
    }
}

func travel(dd map[string]interface{}, key string, value interface{}) {
    vv := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    switch vv.Kind() {
    case reflect.Map:
        m := value.(map[string]interface{})
        dd[key] = m
        for k, v := range m {
            travel(m, k, v)
        }
    case reflect.String:
        dd[key] = value.(string)
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with BSON or Mongo. If you want to reference something for using reflection in this case, you might as well read the source of the `json` package since it's actually relevant.

Comment: I recommend to read bson.M cause the questioner said in the comments, *nested interface{}*, and I think bson.M is an example for decode nested interface{}

Comment: Handling of nesting is simple recursion. JSON does it as well.

Comment: I am new to go and familiar with bson.M, sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this also:

```
var inputJson string = "..."

var decoded map[string]map[string]interface{}

json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputJson), &decoded)

test := decoded["data"]["type"]

fmt.Println(test)
// output: domains
```