# How to Unmarshal stream of different types

Tags: json, go

I have a stream of objects of different but known, types and I'm struggling to figure out how to unmarshal the JSON encoded stream into Go structs.

Here is a sample slice for illustration purpose

```
[
    {
        "uid": "xyz1",
        "type": "person",
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "King"
    },
    {
        "uid": "xyz2",
        "type": "thing",
        "car": "benz",
        "shoes": "nike"
    },
    {
        "uid": "xyz3",
        "type": "person",
        "name": "Mary",
        "surname": "Queen"
    }
]
```

As you can see there is a `type` field that informs the receiver about what is the type of the object.

Data maps into the following Go types in the stream which "share" `UID` and `Type` fields:

```
type Person struct {
    UID     string
    Type    string
    Name    string
    Surname string
}

type Thing struct {
    UID   string
    Type  string
    Car   string
    Shoes string
}
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779354/unmarshalling-stream-of-changing-types-into-structs), though unanswered, it's a bit different from what I need to deal with. Instead of being guaranteed a `transaction` keyspace as I've no guarantee what the payload should look like besides the `type` and `uid` fields.

Is there some way to this other than drowning deeply in `reflect` package?

Comment: The *easiest* path forward is probably to unmarshal into a `[]map[string]interface{}`, inspect each item for its `type`, and then use [`mapstructure`](github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) to convert the map into the appropriate struct.

Comment: I will have a look at that thanks @Adrian. Before I took a deep breath someone managed to downvote my question again :D Classic.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453782/unmarshal-dynamic-json-based-on-a-type-key).

Comment: «Before I took a deep breath someone managed to downvote my question again :D Classic.» your question lacks any display of your attempted solution. That is, you have formulated a question, hinted at that you have googled for a solution but appear to have ended up empty-handed, and posted a question on SO instead of trying to solve the problem. This is classic to no lesser a degree than downvoting such questions so you may consider taking no offence about that.

Comment: FWIW I did not downvote, and I'm with Adrian on this (just in your case it appears you can unmarshal to `[]map[string]string` which is more effective and easy to wield).

Comment: I have made more than one attempt at solving this, ultimately ending up neck-deep in `reflect` package which is what I'm currently doing. I've asked whether there is a better less reflect-y way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unmarshal to a slice of [raw messages](https://godocs.io/encoding/json#RawMessage):

```
var elems []json.RawMessage
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &elems)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

For each element in the slice, unmarshal once to find the type and a second time to the specific type:

```
for _, elem := range elems {

    // Pick out the type field.

    var t struct {
        Type string
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(elem, &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Decode to specific type based on value of the type field.

    switch t.Type {
    case "person":
        var p Person
        err := json.Unmarshal(elem, &p)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", p)
    case "thing":
        var t Thing
        err := json.Unmarshal(elem, &t)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", t)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unknown type %s\n", t.Type)
    }

}
```

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BIrH_6jfIrY).